# Can one use an Enum within a @Value

Tags: java, spring, enums

I'm trying to solve a problem.  We are storing our Properties in the database and when our application starts, we have multiple "@Value" throughout the code.  If someone forgets to have that Properties put into the database, it doesn't let the application start.  So I'm looking for a solution to do a check to see if all the Properties are existing that the application is expecting.  My current path is to use this from the applicationContext.xml - the "AppPropertiesConfigurer" extends PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer and implements BeanPostProcessor

```
<!-- Configure CH Properties -->
<bean id="applicationPropertyConfigurer" class="com.chw.base.spring.AppPropertiesConfigurer"
    depends-on="propertiesSessionFactory">
    <property name="applicationCode" value="xyz" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="propertiesSessionFactory" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/build.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

What I've done is created this class that extends that class above. This is will do my checking to see if all the Properties are loaded, if not, an error message is logged.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import com.chg.base.util.CHGProperties;
import com.chw.base.spring.ChwPropertiesConfigurer;
import com.chw.dbobjects.manager.PropertiesId;


public class MyAppPropertiesConfigurer
        extends AppPropertiesConfigurer
{

    private static Log aLog = LogFactory.getLog(PxiPropertiesConfigurer.class);
    private final String aPropertyNotValid = "Property not valid";
    private final String aPropertyNotFound = "Property not found";
    private HashMap<String, String> aPropertiesMap = new HashMap();

    @Override
    protected void 
    loadProperties(Properties pProps)
    throws IOException
    {
        super.loadProperties(pProps);

        getProperties();

        int count = 1;
        for (PropertiesId properties : PropertiesId.values())
        {
            aLog.error("Property " + count + ":" + properties.getPropertiesName());
            testProperty(properties.getPropertiesName());
        }
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(60000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public final void testProperty(String pKey)
    {
        Properties lPropertiesList = CHGProperties.getMappedProperties();
        Object lObject = lPropertiesList.getProperty(pKey);
        if (lObject == null)
        {
            aLog.error(aPropertyNotFound + " " + pKey);
        }
    }
}
```

Above there is a reference to "PropertiesId" - which is this Enum.

```
public enum PropertiesId
{
    CLEAR_VTD_FLAG("clear.vtd.flag"),
    MAIL_FROM("app.mailfrom"),
    FAKE_PROPERTY("fake.property");

    private final String propertiesName;

    PropertiesId(String propertiesName) 
    { 
        this.propertiesName = propertiesName;
    }

    public String getPropertiesName()
    {
        return propertiesName;
    }
}
```

Now in another class I have many @Values that are used throughout the app.  We created a class to house all of them to help with Unit testing, but in hind sight, it is nice to just have them all in one place instead of scattered through the code.  So, I'd like to do this, but Eclipse complains about it.  Is there a simplier way to do this?

```
@Value("${" + PropertiesId.CLEAR_VTD_FLAG + "}")
private boolean aClearVtdFlag;

@Value("${" + PropertiesId.CLEAR_VTD_FLAG + "}")
private boolean aFake;
@Value("${clear.vtd.flag:true}")
private boolean aClearVtdFlag;
```

Perhaps there is a different way to verify that all the Properties exist for an app?

Thanks, Michael

PS: Running Spring 3.2

Comment: *Several* things here:  1)  Values to annotations must be compile-time constants.  Concatenations is not interpreted as a compile-time constant.  2)  Why are you stuck on an old version of Spring?

Comment: @Makoto Concatenations *are* compile-time constants, but these are enums, not strings.

Comment: Would there be a better practice to do this than the approach above?

Answer (score 0):

Using SpEL, you can get around your enum not being a constant by invoking it instead.  Be sure that you'd actually get a boolean-like value, or you're going to run into problems down the road; this will only ever give back  the text `CLEAR_VTD_FLAG`.

```
@Value("#{T(com.example.pkg.to.your.enum.PropertiesId).CLEAR_VTD_FLAG}")
private boolean aClearVtdFlag;
```

Comment: I've tried this, but this is the error I get
'weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [com.someapp.manager.PropertiesId] to required type [boolean]: 
PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomBooleanEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [com.someapp.manager.PropertiesId]`

I thought it would return the String of the CLEAR_VTD_FLAG and not to inject a boolean value...

Comment: @schu777:  "Be sure that you'd actually get a boolean-like value, or you're going to run into problems down the road; this will only ever give back the text `CLEAR_VTD_FLAG`."

Answer (score 0):

Spring maps `@Value("...")` with `enum` by name, for example:

application.properties

```
enum.name1="Marry"
enum.name2="John"
```

enum class

```
public enum Name {
    Marry,
    John;
}
```

where you want to use

```
@Value("enum.name1")
Name name1; //name1 == Mary;
@Value("enum.name2")
Name name2; //name2 == John;
```

only pay attention that they are case sensitive.

A better way is to use @ConfigurationProperties